# Swift 3, Xcode 8 Course - Height Constraint error

Tags: swift, xcode8

On the Xcode App. I am getting an error thrown after attempting to login or register a new user - which both take the user to the same screen of where the "chats" are held in the format of table cells. However, the app crashes and I receive the following error (Shown in screenshot attached) It appears to be the height constraints but I am unsure how to fix this.

[Screenshot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LhX2.png)

Comment: Looks like you never set the outlet for your height constraint.

Comment: It's not an error, you set a breakpoint (the blue arrow thing in the left column).  Just drag it off to remove it

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you set a break point on line 3. This would pause execution until you click continue button in debugger control.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, never even noticed that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the breakpoint by clicking and dragging the breakpoint area or you can also right-click on line 3 and got to (Delete Breakpoint) option. Remove it and you can build your project. Hope that helps